# How many simple graph can be drawn of n vertices without lifting pen? Move backward is allowed and do not have to use all vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am trying to enumerate a certain class of simple graphs, which can be "drawn without lifting the pen."  (A graph is simple if it has neither parallel edges nor loops.)

For example, consider the following $6$-vertex graphs:

[image: possible][image: also possible][image: this pattern]

These are all acceptable; you can cross an edge, reverse direction, and cross it again.  Also, you do not have to visit all the vertices, so this is OK:

[image: this pattern]

But the following two are not in my class:

[image: 2 components][image: 3 components]

(There is no vertex at the common intersection point of the lines on right.)

I do not know a name for this class of graphs.

**Given $n$ vertices, how many simple graphs are there on those vertices that can be drawn without lifting the pen?**

Comment: More examples:

[valid]: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtVb5.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5t0u.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC0vN.png

[invalid]: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LccqI.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLgUA.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/709C7.png

Comment: Are you interested in counting these graphs _up to isomorphism_, or if I renumber the vertices is that a new graph?

Comment: (Also, the standard way to describe these graphs is to say that "they have $1$ connected component.")

Comment: @JacobManaker  No, not isomorphic.  Thanks for editing the question !

Comment: @JacobManaker  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk1aF.png  these 2 graphs are different

Comment: A graph has your property if and only if it is connected after removing all isolated vertices. Consequently, you particularly need to enumerate all connected graphs.

Comment: when you say "enumerate" do you mean count them or generate them? (I've seen people use either meaning)

Comment: @gilleain just counting them. a formula or something.

Comment: @kabenyuk  So if I have n vertices. can I do a binomial to choose k vertices from n, which is nCk, then count all possible connected graph with these k vertices?  Will this be a right approach?

Comment: @stary It's possible that your approach is the right one and will ultimately lead to the right result. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_enumeration) you can find a recurrence formula for the number of connected labeled graphs.